# How to update image src from static method in code behind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to update Image src from code behind but the image doesn't get updated. I have a Default.aspx page with Image control added to it. The control is placed inside an update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div id="targetDiv" class="auto-style2" runat="server">
      <img id="testID" src="Images/Locations/PERRAN_SANDS.svg" runat="server" />
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have a static method in my code behind and I am trying to update the image src from it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session["ImageControl"] = Page.FindControl("testID");
}

[WebMethod]
public static void GetLocationNames()
{
     String siteName = Database.GetsiteNameforTopPlayer();
    UpdateImage(siteName); 
}

public static string UpdateImage(string imgName)
{
  string filename = imgName+ ".svg";
  string path = @"Images/Locations/" + filename;

  System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage imgControl = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage();
  imgControl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ImageControl"] as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage;
  imgControl.Src = path;
  imgControl.DataBind();
}
```

GetLocationNames() is called from a jquery function. I have breakpoints set in my Code and the value of Src gets updated but the change is not reflected on the webpage

Comment: when is this UpdateImage method being called? I can't see anything in your code that would actually cause the method to run.

Comment: I think it will help if you put an `<asp... />` tag in there so you can access it from code-behind.

Comment: @ADyson: Sorry I forgot to include the method which calls UpdateImage() in the code above.

Comment: @Sometowngeek: Thank you! Will try that :)

Comment: @Sometowngeek runat="server" on a normal HTML tag should make it accessible as a HTMLControl object from the code-behind. That shouldn't be the problem

Comment: @Sugan88 in that case can you please edit the question to show how and where it's called? It could potentially be of significance.

Comment: @ADyson: I have updated the question. Sorry I didn't include it the first time

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to test whether `GetLocationNames()` actually being run? An UpdatePanel doesn't normally call a WebMethod (you'd do that via ajax) and equally from a WebMethod you can't access the other page controls (because you're not in a normal postback context). I strongly suspect this code is not running at all. If you're using an updatepanel I think you need a) a way of triggering the UpdatePanel, and b) just a normal event handling method (not a WebMethod) to respond to that trigger and run your UpdateImage method.

Comment: Thanks ADyson! I am doing it via ajax now and it updates the image src.

Answer (score 0):

even can do in the page_Load event , by using

```
 string filename = imgName+ ".svg";
  string path = @"Images/Locations/" + filename;
testID.Src=path;
```